# Не работают StaticFiles в Django 2.0

Tags: css, веб-программирование, django, localhost, static

(!) В чем проблема:
Не применяется css staticfile на локальном сервере. 
1) HTML5 код:

```
{% load static %}
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="ru">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 <title> Welcome Page </title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
 </head>
```

2) В settings.py есть

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [...'django.contrib.staticfiles'...]
```

3) Также в settings.py есть:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

5) В папке static есть файл css/main.css . Файловая структура следующая: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(!) Что пробовал:

1) Статьи в интернете, одна из последних: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Django-loading-static-files

 2) Видео-уроки на ютубе: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ETQf3TQ9gc , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAKqDLjwIXI 

 Все вышепросмотренное привело меня к тому, что имею сейчас.

 Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `myproject` есть в `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @andreymal т.е. добавить это: INSTALLED_APPS = [...'myproject', ...] ? Это не работает, или Вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: Это. Тогда поясните подробнее, что значит «не работает», как запускаете джангу, где находится manage.py (если есть)

Comment: @andreymal Файловая структура(P.S.как видите,там есть несколько папок static с одинаковым содержимым в разных директориях, просто я пытался понять, где ее нужно разместить): https://photos.app.goo.gl/aLGUgQFqGZVDZr6N7

Comment: "Не работает" = не находятся статические файлы (css, img..) для html кода. Когда не был подключен Django, все работало. Сервер запускаю: $ python3 manage.py runserver 8445

Comment: DEBUG=True в настройках стоит?

Comment: @andreymal Да, стоит

Answer (score 0):

Если статику будет обрабатывать джанго, то можно и так пути писать без всяких load static:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
```

Чтобы это работало при выключенном debug, то следует запускать с дополнительным параметром:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.109:9000 --insecure
```